# How to initialize a field in viewModel with suspend method

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, suspend

How to initialize a field in view model if I need to call the suspend function to get the value?

I a have suspend function that returns value from a database.

```
suspend fun fetchProduct(): Product
```

When I create the view model I have to get product in this field

```
private val selectedProduct: Product
```

I tried doing it this way but it doesn't work because I'm calling this method outside of the coroutines

```
private val selectedProduct: Product = repository.fetchProduct()
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize a field in the way you described. `suspend` function must be called from a coroutine or another `suspend` function. To launch a coroutine there are a couple of builders for that: `CoroutineScope.launch`, `CoroutineScope.async`, `runBlocking`. The latter is not recommended to use in production code. There are also a couple of builders - `liveData`, `flow` -  which can be used to initialize the field. For your case I would recommend to use a [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) or [`Flow`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#create) to observe the field initialization. The sample code, which uses the `liveData` builder function to call a `suspend` function:

```
val selectedProduct: LiveData<Product> = liveData {
    val product = repository.fetchProduct()
    emit(product)
}
```

And if you want to do something in UI after this field is initialized you need to [observe](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects) it. In `Activity` or `Fragment` it will look something like the following:

```
// Create the observer which updates the UI.
val productObserver = Observer<Product> { product ->
    // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
    productNameTextView.text = product.name
}

// Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
viewModel.selectedProduct.observe(this, productObserver)
```

For `liveData`, use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0` or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Since `fetchProduct()` is a suspend function, you have to invoke it inside a coroutine scope.

For you case I would suggest the following options:

1. Define `selectedProduct` as nullable and initialize it inside your `ViewModel` as `null`:

```
class AnyViewModel : ViewModel {

    private val selectedProduct: Product? = null
    

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            selectedProduct = repository.fetchProduct()
        }
    }
}
```

2. Define selectedProduct as a `lateinit var` and do the same as above;

Personally I prefer the first cause I feel I have more control over the fact that the variable is defined or not.

Comment: this is a bad practice, you have no way of knowing if there's actually a value or not and you'd have to check the variable multiple times hoping for there to be something, [livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) is the perfect solution for this

Comment: you are right. I just wanted to be more practical with OP's question, which is how to initialize a variable returned by a suspend function.

Comment: Why do this in `init` block?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do that on `init`, it's just that, since OP asked how to initialize the `ViewModel` with a value returned from a suspend function, `init` seemed a nice place to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the function inside a coroutine scope to get the value.

if you're in a ViewModel() class you can safely use the viewModelScope

```
private lateinit var selectedProduct:Product

fun initialize(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        selectedProduct = repository.fetchProduct()
    }
}
```

Comment: But then the field will not be safe

Comment: Well you could make it nullable and null-check it whenever you want to use it. There's sadly no way to it 100% safe when you're relying on an asynchronous call to initialize a field.

Comment: this is a bad practice, you have no way of knowing if there's actually a value or not and you'd have to check the variable multiple times hoping for there to be something, [livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) is the perfect solution for this

Comment: I was providing a solution to OP's problem, not an architectural design pattern...

Comment: Always LiveData is just a value container, and does not solve OP's problem in any way. Do you even know what you are talking about?

Comment: @a_local_nobody how to solve this proble with livedata or flow?

Comment: `Do you even know what you are talking about?` there's no need to be rude, and yes, i do know what i'm talking about, live data isn't just an architectural design, it has very little to do with architecture at all, if you use live data you can observe onto it in the activity/fragment so that you actually know when the value has been assigned, then there's no need for you to rely on `selectedProduct` being populated by something else, you can directly be told when it does have a value

Comment: How about you provice a actual solution instead of just calling "bad practice" on someone's answer (talking about rudeness). You still have yet to provide OP with a solution using LiveData...